# Get rid of points that are over 500m from previous time point

Tags: point, distance, buffer, time

I have gps data from animals over time. The collars recorded the location of the animal every 15 minutes, but there are some funky points that are obviously an error as the animal could not have moved that far in 15 minutes. I want to exclude any points that are >500 m away from the previous time point. Is there a way to do this using a tool in Arc gis pro, or if I need to use python could someone explain how?